# Как правильно использовать GenerateExportHeader чтобы избежать ошибки 'mylib_exort.h': No such file?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

Попробовал воспользоваться [GenerateExportHeader](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/GenerateExportHeader.html). Вещь должна быть очень интересной - с ней не придётся делать `mylib_export.h` и следить за тем правильно ли заданы макросы экспорта/импорта. Сделал всё по инструкции: в `CMakeLists.txt` добавил

```
add_library(mylib SHARED ${projectSources})
include(GenerateExportHeader)
generate_export_header(mylib)
```

в хедере всё и так уже было:

```
#include "mylib_export.h"
class MYLIB_EXPORT SomeClass {
  ...
};
```

Но, вот при сборке получаю

```
projects\mylib\someclass.h(7): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mylib_export.h': No such file or directory
```

Не пойму, что не так?

Comment: `target_include_directories(mylib PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})` ?

Comment: да, вот не помогло или я не так делал. Этот хедер не добавился в инсталл и в итоге ругается уже там где эта либа используется. Я это к тому, что раз мне всё равно надо следить за подключением mylib_export.h к разным таргетам, то в чём профит generate_export_header? Ну и `target_include_directories(mylib PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})` ну, как-то не то. Тогда уж заморочиться с `GeneratedFiles`

Answer (score 1):

В общем, красиво сделать не вышло.

```
function(GENERATE_EXPORT target)
    set(libGeneratedDir ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/generated_files/${target})
    set(libExportsHeader ${libGeneratedDir}/${target}_exports.h)
    generate_export_header(${target}
        BASE_NAME ${target}
        EXPORT_FILE_NAME ${libExportsHeader}
    )
    get_target_property(publicHeaders ${target} PUBLIC_HEADER)
    list(APPEND publicHeaders ${libExportsHeader})
    set_target_properties(${target} PROPERTIES PUBLIC_HEADER "${publicHeaders}")
    target_include_directories(${target} PUBLIC $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${libGeneratedDir}>)
endfunction()

GENERATE_EXPORT(mylib)
```

Можно было и без функции сделать и `libExportsHeader` сразу добавить к списку заголовков для `install`, но я решил, что не за чем плодить бесполезные переменные. К тому же, `GENERATE_EXPORT(mylib)` - делает именно то, что я ожидал от `generate_export_header`

Comment: Для добавления элемента в список-свойство, вместо 3 вызовов `get_target_property`, `list(APPEND)` и `set_target_property` можно использовать один вызов [set_property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_property.html) с опцией APPEND: `set_property(TARGET ${target} APPEND PROPERTY PUBLIC_HEADER ${libExportsHeader})`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, давно не трогал этот кусок, не помню почему в три строки. Можешь выложить свой рабочий оттестированый вариант, будет что принять в качестве ответа.